# How do I turn days into functions of hours in Excel?

Tags: excel, days

I have a long time-series dataset and to accomplish my goal, I need to know when the days start and end along my data.

I know the data points were collected hourly, hence, I need to average every 24 row values to get an average valeu for any particular day. Here's a part of how I am setting up an spreadsheet for this task.

[image: Hour/Days]

I know day one is 01/01/2010 and the last day is 12/31/2015.

On the first slot for "Day" beside "Hour" 0:00 I'll write 01/01/2010 and I want that value to repeat for the next 24 hours. When it reaches a new 0:00 hour, I want to add one more day to the day I previously had, thus, one will be seeing 01/02/2010 for the next 0:00 in the dataset.

Assuming "Hour" is in column A and "Day" in column B, I thought of writing 01/01/2010 for B2, and for B3 I'd write:

```
=if(A3="0:00";B2+1;B)
```

but it didn't work properly.

Is there a bult-in function that allows me to do that? I know days follow their natural occurring sequence in Excel but as to how to link a day to its period of 24 hours, I have no idea.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel understands dates *and* times. If you enter a date and then format it as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm (using the format menu on the ribbon and choosing "More Number Formats..."/"Custom") you will see that the result has *both* a time and a date. Excel stores dates and times using a single number: what you see depends on the way you have formatted the result.

If you add 1 to the date, this will add a day. Likewise, if you add 1/24 to the date, you will add one *hour* to the date. Using this approach you can create a sequence of date-times that increments in hours (and you can always changes the increment by adding something other than 1/24).

Comment: Thanks, matt_black. But as I said, the formula I used didn't work. After it got to the next 0:00, the day didn't change. if I were to use this formula for the entire time series, I'd still be seeing only one day, 01/01/2007.

Comment: Actually, I just edited the question. The formula I'm using has quotes around 0:00. If I don't use them, Excel returns an error.

Comment: Matt_Black, I see what you meant. Very creative. I had no idea Excel could interpret time this way. Thank you for your feedback. Just one more question though: do you know if there is a bult-in function to link a day to its 24-hour period?